# how to access a class within a form that has the same name as a class in another form

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to create a data collection page with multiple forms that each use the same function to append an array. the problem is that I can't figure out how to access the data on the forms.

What I have so far:

Notice that the JavaScript code adds events to the buttons of each form and the `productList();`

function is supposed to extract the values from the hidden input controls.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const product1 = document.querySelector("#productId_1")
  const product2 = document.querySelector("#productId_2")
  const product3 = document.querySelector("#productId_3")

  product1.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formId = "#productId_1";
    productList(formId);
  });

  product2.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formId = "#productId_2";
    productList(formId);
  });

  product3.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formId = "#productId_3";
    productList(formId);
  });
});


function productList(formId) {

  var a = document.getElementById(formId).getElementsByClassName("productId")[0];

  //testing
  alert(formId, a);
}
```

```html
<div class="productContainer">
  <h1 class="productTitle">Products:</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="product" id="productId_1">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_1">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="product" id="productId_2">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_2">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container" class="product" id="productId_3">
    <form action="" class="product">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_3">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You used `getElementById` in your `productList` function, but you are passing `#productId_1` to it - this needs to be just `productId_1`; getElementById takes the actual ID value only, it is _not_ working based on a CSS selector. (Or you could also switch to `querySelector` at this point, _then_ `#productId_1` would be correct.)

Comment: And you want the value of that hidden input field, currently you are only selecting the element itself - needs to be `.getElementsByClassName("productId")[0].value`

Comment: And `alert` takes only _one_ parameter, so even if your `a` there contains anything, you will never see it. (And you should really rather switch to using `console.log` for such debugging purposes anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` takes only the `id` value, not the `#` selector syntax.  So this:

```
var formId = "#productId_1";
```

should be this:

```
var formId = "productId_1";
```

Additionally, you'll find that `console.log` produces more useful information than `alert`.  So this:

```
alert(formId, a);
```

should be this:

```
console.log(formId, a);
```

With that, the code is working.  `formId` is the `id` of the selected `<form>` and `a` is the hidden `<input>`.  You can get its value with `a.value`.

For example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() =>{
    const product1 = document.querySelector("#productId_1")
    const product2 = document.querySelector("#productId_2")
    const product3 = document.querySelector("#productId_3")

    product1.addEventListener("submit",e=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        var formId = "productId_1";
        productList(formId);
    });

    product2.addEventListener("submit",e=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        var formId = "productId_2";
        productList(formId);
    });

    product3.addEventListener("submit",e=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        var formId = "productId_3";
        productList(formId);
    });
});


function productList(formId){
    var a = document.getElementById(formId).getElementsByClassName("productId")[0];
    //testing
    console.log(formId, a.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="productContainer">
  <h1 class="productTitle">Products:</h1>
  <div class="container">
      <form action="" class="product" id="productId_1">
          <h1>balls</h1>
          <p>a ball bering</p>
          <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_1">
          <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
      </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
      <form action="" class="product" id="productId_2">
          <h1>balls</h1>
          <p>a ball bering</p>
          <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_2">
          <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
      </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container" class="product" id="productId_3">
      <form action="" class="product">
          <h1>balls</h1>
          <p>a ball bering</p>
          <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_3">
          <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume you do not know all the id's and you may have more elements (forms) with that class at a later point in time.

```js
function productList(formId) {
  const a = document.getElementById(formId).getElementsByClassName("productId")[0];
  //testing
  alert(formId, a);
}

function onSubmitHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formId = event.target.id;
  productList(formId);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
  [...forms].forEach(form => form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmitHandler));
});
```

```html
<div class="productContainer">
  <h1 class="productTitle">Products:</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="product" id="productId_1">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_1">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="product" id="productId_2">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_2">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container" class="product" id="productId_3">
    <form action="" class="product">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_3">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must remove `#` from parameter `formId` to works with `document.getElementById`

see live playground https://codepen.io/dimaslanjaka/pen/YzJMKJa

```
<div class="productContainer">
  <h1 class="productTitle">Products:</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="product" id="productId_1">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_1">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="product" id="productId_2">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_2">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container" class="product" id="productId_3">
    <form action="" class="product">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="item_3">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
console.clear();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const product1 = document.querySelector("#productId_1");
  const product2 = document.querySelector("#productId_2");
  const product3 = document.querySelector("#productId_3");

  product1.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    productList(this.id);
  });

  product2.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    productList(this.id);
  });

  product3.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    productList(this.id);
  });
});

function productList(formId) {
  const a = document.getElementById(formId);
  let hiddenInput;

  if (a) {
    hiddenInput = a.getElementsByClassName("productId")[0];
  }

  //testing
  alert(`hidden input of form #${formId} has value ${hiddenInput.value}`);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating forms it is often not necessary to use IDs. Use the name attribute instead -- both for the form and for all the form fields.

You already have event listeners for all the forms. I made a shorter version of that. You can also se a commented out line that you can get a specific form with the dot notation on the `document.forms` list.

When you use the [addEventListener() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) the parameter in the callback function is an event object (here the submit event). The event holds all the information about the event. For the submit event, what form was submitted etc. So, in the callback function (here `productList(e)`) the `e.target` is the form and with the dot notation you can get all the form fields that has a name, like `e.target.productId.value` to get the value from that input element.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  // for each form in the document
  [...document.forms].forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', productList);
  });
  // a specific form
  //document.forms.productId_1.addEventListener('submit', productList);
});

function productList(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.productId.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="productContainer">
  <h1 class="productTitle">Products:</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="product" name="productId_1">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="item_1">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="product" name="productId_2">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="item_2">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container" class="product">
    <form action="" class="product" name="productId_3">
      <h1>balls</h1>
      <p>a ball bering</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="item_3">
      <button class="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```